# Kotlin Flow with initial value, replay = 1, no duplicates, no conflation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I need to transfer a stream of values from a publisher / producer to one or multiple consumers / subscribers / observers. The exact requirements are:

1. the "stream" has a default value
2. consumers receive the last published value when they subscribe (the last value is replayed)
3. the last published value can also be retrieved via a `value` property
4. two consecutive published values are distinct (no duplicates)
5. all published values need to be received by the consumer (values cannot be [conflated](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/conflate.html))
6. consumption happens via a [`FlowCollector`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow-collector/)
7. the implementation must be multiplatform (Android, iOS, JS)

`MutableStateFlow` is meeting almost all of these requirements except item #5:

> Updates to the value are always conflated. So a slow collector skips fast updates, but always collects the most recently emitted value
> (https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/).

So something like this:

```
val flow = MutableStateFlow(0)

// runs in co-routine 1
flow.collect {
    println("Collect: $it")
    delay(100)
}

// runs in co-routine 2
repeat(10) {
    flow.emit(it + 1)
}
```

will print 0 and 10 but not the numbers in between because the collector is slow and emitted values are conflated

I could use `MutableSharedFlow`:

```
val flow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(replay = 1, extraBufferCapacity = 1)
```

`MutableSharedFlow` doesn't conflate values but 1) has no `value` property (there's `last()` but that's a suspend function), 2) allows duplicates and 3) has no initial values.
While it's possible to add these three requirements, adding the `value` property and the duplicate check isn't trivial.

I could use a BehaviorSubject:

```
val subject = BehaviorSubject(0)
val flow = subject.asFlow().distinctUntilChanged()
```

That would work perfectly but I'd have to add https://github.com/badoo/Reaktive just for this.

So here's my question: is there a Kotlin Flow solution that meets all the requirements without having to add the missing pieces "manually" (like with `MutableSharedFlow`)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not so bad to add the missing pieces you want to `MutableSharedFlow` to have exactly the syntax you want:

```kotlin
class MutableBehaviorFlow<T : Any?>(
    private val initialValue: T,
    private val _backingSharedFlow: MutableSharedFlow<T> = MutableSharedFlow(
        replay = 1,
        extraBufferCapacity = Int.MAX_VALUE,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.SUSPEND
    )
) : MutableSharedFlow<T> by _backingSharedFlow {
    init {
        tryEmit(initialValue)
    }

    val value: T
        get() = try {
            replayCache.last()
        } catch (_: NoSuchElementException) {
            initialValue
        }

    override suspend fun emit(value: T) {
        if (value != this.value) _backingSharedFlow.emit(value)
    }

    override fun tryEmit(value: T): Boolean =
        if (value != this.value) _backingSharedFlow.tryEmit(value)
        else true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is close to what I need. The problem is the duplicate check not being threadsafe. There's quite a bit that can happen between reading the value from the cache and actually updating it. That's why I said it's not trivial. A mutex would probably do the job.

Comment: BTW with your solution the initial value is not emitted because `tryEmit(initialValue)` calls its own `tryEmit` function which checks for duplicates. The getter for `value` at that point throws a `NoSuchElementException` and thus the getter returns `initialValue` -> `_backingSharedFlow.tryEmit(value)` is never called. the `init` block should do `_backingSharedFlow.tryEmit(initialValue)` instead.